# breaking long html code into separate lines

Tags: html

I am trying to enter this into a form for testing purposes but the string is too long.  I need to break it up into multiple lines but still keep the code readable by a browser.  Is there a way to do that? If I just line break by hitting "Enter" the code string isn't recognized anymore

```
<img src=x onerror="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">
```

Comment: does your form allow you to enter some javascript ?  It's the only option I can think of.

Comment: Yes it does allow javascript

Comment: did you finally find out how to solve ? `document.write()` isn't recommended but works, the other way is to have `<img id="someId"/>` and then using way to concatenate your string into a var `varOnError` and `document.getElementById('someId').setAttribute('onerror', varOnError)` should do the trick.